# Cannot ready property of '0' of undefined - Pulling data from an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm creating a quiz app using Javascript and I've come across an error that is puzzling me so I decided to post it on here and maybe someone sees something different then me.

### I have an object of arrays called `quizQ` --- inside this object is my question and answer list. It is structured like this - I should mention that `testbank` does get initialized into `quizQ` in another function in my script file and all the console.logs confirm this, so the problem must lie in the `for` loop

```
var testBank = [
    {
        qTitle: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
        picks: ["strings", "booleans", "alerts", "numbers"],
        ans: "alerts"
      },
      {
        qTitle: "The condition in an if / else statement is enclosed within ____.",
        picks: ["quotes", "curly brackets", "parentheses", "square brackets"],
        ans: "parentheses"
      },
      {
        qTitle: "Is JavaScript fun to work with?",
        picks: ["No", "Sometimes", "What is Javascript", "Not just yes, but HELL YES!"],
        ans: "Not just yes, but HELL YES!"
      },
      {
        qTitle: "DOM is an abreviation for ____",
        picks: ["Data Object Mode", "Dumb Old Man", "Document Object Model", "Dutle Opo Mipsy"],
        ans: "Document Object Model"
      },
```

--- Pretty simple questions I pulled from another app on Github. So what I've done is created a function that will put these `picks` in a list so I can choose the one I want to answer with. I use the qTitle as the header for each question and after you complete it you are presented with another. ---

The problem is when I run the function and I run the `for` loop for it, it keeps telling me It cannot read undefined of '0' which is the first index the `for` runs over. Here is my code

```
 current = quizQ.pop();
    console.log(current)
    let questionServed = document.createElement('h2');

    questionServed.setAttribute("question", current.qTitle);
    questionServed.textContent = current.qTitle;
    testEl.appendChild(questionServed)

    let choices = document.createElement('ul');

    choices.setAttribute('id', 'choices'); 
    testEl.appendChild(choices)
    
    for (let i = 0; i < current.picks.length; i++) {
        let pickList = document.createElement('li')
        pickList.setAttribute('pick-value', current.pick[i]);
        pickList.setAttribute('id', 'questionNum' + i);
        pickList.textContent = current.pick[i];

        choices.appendChild(pickList)
        
    }
```

I've `console.log(current)` and it returns the last array in the testBank as expected, however when the `for` loop runs, it keeps giving me the error mentioned above. I assume I'm writing the statement incorrectly `current.pick[i]` but I assumed that it would go into current, then picks, and pull out the `pick[0]` which would be one of the options given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change `current.pick[i]` for `current.picks[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A good plan to avoid this is to have a convention that arrays are named with a plural

In your case the problem is `pick` versus `picks`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < current.picks.length; i++) {
    let pickList = document.createElement('li')
    pickList.setAttribute('pick-value', current.picks[i]);
    pickList.setAttribute('id', 'questionNum' + i);
    pickList.textContent = current.picks[i];

    choices.appendChild(pickList)
```

It is often difficult to remember whether the array is `picks` or `pick`. After all, when you select one element, you think to yourself that you are selecting element #3, so why shouldn't it be called `pick[3]`?

A convention to avoid this is that the array should be called `picks`, and an individual value from the array, if you need to extract it as a single item, you can call `pick`.

Sticking to this convention makes it easier to avoid the problem.

Comment: I hope you know, we aren't gonna talk about this. I'm gonna pretend I didn't post anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a typo with current.pick. Ensure all members are named correctly and consider using Typescript for future error checking.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html